# Intermittent Internal server error in Google Cloud Composer web UI - error code 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

We are getting this error on-and-off since 01/22 on Composer UI, the airflow dags seems to be running fine, the web UI however having the problem. Google cloud status page indicates there is no issue, changing browser or connection through other wifi / mobile hotspot doesn't help either. Not sure what's going on.

```
An internal server error occurred while authorizing your request. Error code 1
```

location: us-central1-c

version: composer-1.7.3-airflow-1.10.2

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Composer is a managed workflow automation tool, so I don't think that you can address this issue directly.

For more context on what is happening, [Cloud Composer architecture](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/overview#architecture) states that the Airflow Web Server is inside of a [Tenant project](https://cloud.google.com/service-infrastructure/docs/glossary#tenant), which is a isolated environment used for deploying managed services, this is for unified Cloud Identity and Access Management (IAM) access control and an additional layer of data security. Given that the error states that something is failing when authorizing, this issue may be related to the Cloud IAM service.

I recommend you to open a new case from the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) in the Support section, and ask for further assistance in this issue.